# Variable not get anything

Tags: node.js

I am running a code in nodejs that does console.log from variable without problems, but then the variable `a` does not contain anything:

```
var a='';
var util   = require('util'),
    exec  = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('ifconfig eth0',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         a=stdout.toString();
         console.log(a);
})
```

Is there anything wrong that makes it not store the `stdout` message to variable `a`?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an error executing `ifconfig eth0`, then there will be no value in `stdout`. For example, my machine doesn't actually have an interface named `eth0`, so nothing is returned in `stdout`.

Try executing `ifconfig eth0` manually to see what happens. You could also modify your code like this:

```
var a='',b='';
var util   = require('util'),
    exec  = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('ifconfig eth0',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         a=stdout.toString();
         b=stderr.toString();
         console.log(a);
         console.log(b);
})
```

---

Alternatively, perhaps you mean that the `console.log` does actually log the output to the console, but the variable `a` then appears to be empty?

If this is the case, make sure you are accessing `a` at the right time. Simply trying to read `a` after the last line of the code you posted would not work, since the callback that sets `a=stdout.toString()` would not have run yet.

Answer (score 0):

tanks for reply I found the problem,
Its true that I need to have in consideration  stderr but the code is only a small demo
I solve the problem declaring variable a as an array  var a= []

```
var a= []

var util   = require('util'),
    exec  = require('child_process').exec,
    child;

child = exec('ifconfig eth0',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
         a[0]=stdout.toString();

})
```

Now variable a contains the string from stdout for future usage

Consider this post SOLVED

Regards